# Display title on modally presented view in Swift 5

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am using Xcode 11.2.1, Swift 5, and have a view that is presented Modally. Via storyboard I added a navigation  bar and have two navigation items, left, cancel, right, save. I am trying to get the title of the view to display. I have tried via viewDidLoad

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "New " + costumeChoice

    imageFromFileButton.alpha = 0.5
    imageFromFileButton.isEnabled = false

    costumeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "PauPlaceholder")
}
```

I have tried "self.navigationItem.title = "New " + costumeChoice" through viewWillAppear and through viewDidAppear, but no luck.

What am I missing?,

Answer (score 1):

You have to present the NavigationController which embedded your ViewController, that way a navigationBar will be presented. 
For example:

Assuming that your current ViewController is `CurrentViewController`

and viewController which you want to present is `DestinationViewController`

In order to present the destinationController you have to do this: -

```
// self ==> CurrentViewController
self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController:DestinationViewController(), animated: true)
```